# Laravel - How to Get List of Employees not in the Leave table

Tags: laravel

I have this two tables/models:

```
class HrEmployee extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hr_employees';

    protected $fillable = [
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'employee_code',
              ];


    public function leaverequest(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Hr\HrLeaveRequest');
    }  
}



class HrLeaveRequest extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'hr_leave_requests';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
                  'id',
                  'employee_id',
                  'department_id',
              ];


    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrEmployee','employee_id');
    }


    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrDepartment','department_id');
    }

}
```

Using the controller function below, how do I use Eloquent Query to

1. get the List of Employees and their departments (first_name, last_name, employee_code, department_name) who are in the hr_leave_requests (HrLeaveRequest) table
2. count the Employees and their departments (first_name, last_name, employee_code, department_name) who are in the hr_leave_requests (HrLeaveRequest) table

   ```
      public function leave_request_approve()
      {
         $employee_not_in_list          = HrLeaveRequest...;

    }
   ```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)** and **[Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)** like below :

```
HrEmployee::with('leaverequest')->has('leaverequest')->get();
```